# Alert message when there is duplicate email

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show an alert message when there is duplicate email address.

Here is my code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("contactpersonen-email", function(value, element) {
    var parentForm = $(element).closest('form');
    var timeRepeated = 0;
    if (value != '') {
        $(parentForm.find(':text')).each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === value) {
                timeRepeated++;
            }
        });
    }
    return timeRepeated === 1 || timeRepeated === 0;
    alert('duplicate');
}, "Email adres bestaat al");
```

But it doesn't work. Could you find out the problem and make it working?

Comment: For a start you are alerting after the return statement, try putting it before

Comment: Can you provide the html pls ?

Comment: you placed alert message after return statement which is not reachable to execute or call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.validator.addMethod("contactpersonen-email", function(value, element) {
    var parentForm = $(element).closest('form');
    var timeRepeated = 0;
    if (value != '') {
        $(parentForm.find(':text')).each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() === value) {
                timeRepeated++;
            }
        });
    }
    var ok = timeRepeated === 1 || timeRepeated === 0;
    if(!ok) alert('duplicate');
    return ok;
}, "Email adres bestaat al");
```

Comment: Hi Adder. Thank you!! very nice